Changing the moving average duration for TradingView Advanced Real-Time Chart Widget
The default length for the moving average on TradingView Advanced Real-Time Chart Widget is 9 days but I am trying to change it to 50.
I looked online and only found out how to change the moving average length for Advanced charts but I am using TradingView Advanced Real-Time Chart Widget.
 // TradingViewWidget.tsx
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, memo } from "react";

const TechnicalAnalysis: React.FC = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;

    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-advanced-chart.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.async = true;
    script.innerHTML = `
    {
      "autosize": true,
      "symbol": "CME:LBR1!",
      "interval": "D",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "dark",
      "style": "1",
      "locale": "en",
      "hide_side_toolbar": false,
      "allow_symbol_change": true,
      "save_image": false,
      "calendar": false,
      "studies": [
        "STD;SMA"
      ],
      "support_host": "https://www.tradingview.com"
    }`;

    containerRef.current.appendChild(script);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box height="90vh" sx={{ border: "1px var(--black) solid" }}>
      <Box className="tradingview-widget-container" ref={containerRef}>
        <Box className="tradingview-widget-container__widget" />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default memo(TechnicalAnalysis);


